# Given I is bounded. Show if f: I → R is uniformly continuous on I, then f is bounded on I.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

a) Let I be a bounded interval. Prove that if $f: I → \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous on $I$, then f is bounded on $I$.

Proof: Suppose $I$ is a bounded interval, such that $I = (a,b)$. Then given $f: (a,b) → \mathbb{R}$,  by theorem, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ iff $f$ can be continuously extended to $[a,b]$; that is there is a continuous function $g: [a,b] → \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for $x$ in $(a,b)$.

Then since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I$, there is a continuous function $g(x)$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ on $[a,b]$.

Then $[a,b]$ is closed and bounded, so $g$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. Thus $f$ is also bounded on $I$.

b) Prove that part a) may be false if $I$ is unbounded or if $f$ is merely continuous.

Can someone please give a counterexample for part b).

Does my proof for part a) fine? Please can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The only possible issue I see with your proof is then end points, that is, how do you know that $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f(b)=g(b)$?

Comment: By the above theorem , f is uniformly continuous if and only if f can be extended to [a,b]. Since f is uniformly continuous, then there is a g such that g(x) = f(x). This is just a theorem I am using/

Comment: Since you are learning analysis, you should try and prove that if $f$ is a continuous function on a compact set $K$, then $f$ attains its supremum and infimum on $K$.

Comment: @use2486, Ah, okay. I'm also taking an Intro to Analysis Course and we did not spend time on Uniformly continuous exercises.

Answer (score 1):

$I=\mathbb{R}$ unbounded: $f(x)=x$ is uniformly continuous but unbounded.

$I=(0,1)$ bounded, $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous.